# Python: Are sparse diagonal matrices more computationally efficent?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, diagonal

I have a function which currently multiplies a matrix in scipy.sparse.csr_matrix form by a vector. I use this function for different values lots of times and I would like the matrix * vector multiplication to be as efficient as possible. The matrix is an N x N matrix, but only contains m x N non-zero elements, where m << N. The non-zero elements are currently arranged randomly about the matrix. I could perform row operations to get this matrix in a form such that all the elements appear on only m + 2 diagonals. Then use scipy.sparse.dia_matrix instead of scipy.sparse.csr_matrix. It will take quite a bit of work so I was wondering if anyone knows if this will even improve the computational efficiency?

Comment: The `dia` format does not have its own matrix multiplication code.  Most, if not all, sparse calculations are done in the `csr` format.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So we can conclude that it will make no difference to the computation time?

Comment: Even if the product code was good, a diagonal compression is not nearly as useful if there's more than one non zero diagonal because you need to access more than one non-contiguous array element per row or column. For csr/csc you just need the one pointer and a length to get everything you need.